# What are my options to nicely format an AppleScript dialog?

Tags: applescript

I've done an Applescript script to get some additional information on a photo app.
This only presents info with an OK dialog.

What are my options if I want to format the output beyond AppleScript native capabilities (which are very poor) ?
For example, doing some text formatting, justification and choosing the color of the dialog window.

I understood I could use Xcode that for, but my understanding is that I would have to learn another language, and parse the output produced by AppleScript, which is rather tedious.
Would it still be reactive ? Say, only a couple seconds added to the time of execution.
And that is under the hypothesis I could invoke my original AS script in that environment.

Are this assumptions correct and could I have some more details ?

Also could I also use this environment to input information to an AppleScript?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: The built-in dialogs are not customizable, but most of the Cocoa frameworks are available via AppleScriptObjC.  Xcode isn’t necessarily needed, AppleScriptObjC can also be edited and in most cases run from the Script Editor.  Exactly what kind of dialog or formatting are you looking for?

Comment: As it is a photo application, I would like to make it nicer on the eye; changing the back color to black, the font to white, maybe centered justification, different font size to get hierarchization, bold, this kind of stuff. What environment is needed to code in AppleScriptObjC ?

Comment: AppleScriptObjC is just AppleScript with a few additions to be able to call Cocoa methods; the Script Editor or Xcode can be used.  Sounds like an NSTextField could be used in an NSAlert (although alerts are pretty ugly these days with that vertical layout).

Comment: You might take a quick look at two of the libraries available on [Late Night Software's](https://latenightsw.com/freeware/) site — Dialog Toolkit Plus v1.1.3, Myriad Tables Lib v1.0.10. Might not give you everything you hope but they should give you some options. There are some issues depending upon your OS version but details are there.

Comment: to Mockman : Thanks I actually did that in parallel of writing this post, when I finally found where the code was hosted. I ended up using it , as it is marginally better than the native solution.

Comment: Thanks red_menace. I get I have to look into AppleScriptObjC if I want to get things done my way. Maybe overkill for my needs. I will see.

Comment: It isn't too bad, but I would need to see the dialog layout for any kind of answer.